# How to convert an array into a new array based on a lookup dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a numpy array into a new array by using each value in the existing array and finding its corresponding key from a dictionary. The new array should consist of the corresponding dictionary keys.
Here is what I have:

```
# dictionary where values are lists
available_weights = {0.009174311926605505: [7, 14, 21, 25, 31, 32, 35, 45, 52, 82, 83, 96, 112, 119, 142], 0.009523809523809525: [33, 37, 43, 44, 69, 73, 75, 78, 79, 80, 102, 104, 110, 115, 150], 0.1111111111111111: [91], 0.019230769230769232: [36, 50, 127, 139], 0.010869565217391304: [10, 48, 55, 62, 77, 88, 103, 124, 131, 137, 147], 0.014084507042253521: [2, 3, 4, 22, 27, 30, 41, 53, 87, 122, 123, 132, 143], 0.011494252873563218: [20, 34, 99, 125, 135, 138, 141], 0.045454545454545456: [0, 109], 0.01818181818181818: [49, 64, 72, 90, 146, 148], 0.07142857142857142: [106], 0.01282051282051282: [16, 63, 68, 98, 114, 130, 145], 0.010638297872340425: [8, 28, 40, 57, 61, 66, 71, 74, 76, 84, 85, 86, 128, 144], 0.02040816326530612: [6, 65], 0.021739130434782608: [29, 67, 92, 93], 0.02127659574468085: [47, 118, 120], 0.011111111111111112: [1, 13, 19, 24, 42, 54, 70, 89, 94, 107, 117, 126, 129, 140], 0.015625: [38, 60, 101, 133, 134, 136], 0.03333333333333333: [56, 58, 97, 121], 0.016666666666666666: [5, 26, 105, 113], 0.014705882352941176: [17, 46, 95]}

# existing numpy array 
train_idx = [134, 45, 137, 140, 79, 98, 128, 80, 99, 71, 145, 35, 94, 122, 77, 23, 113, 44, 68, 21, 20, 125, 74, 139, 29, 109, 25, 34, 6, 81, 22, 114, 12, 95, 150, 106, 84, 19, 58, 59, 88, 143, 136, 43, 72, 132, 117, 13, 65, 111, 39, 14, 56, 11, 26, 90, 119, 112, 27, 57, 46, 147, 123, 16, 36, 100, 141, 38, 62, 32, 75, 146, 89, 37, 31, 40, 64, 87, 3, 103, 102, 104, 78, 53, 1, 142, 47, 130, 105, 4, 93, 52, 42, 10, 9, 115, 76, 54, 49, 116, 69, 5, 86, 66, 101, 107, 96, 110, 8, 73, 121, 138, 67, 124, 108, 97, 120, 2, 148, 127, 135, 18, 149, 82, 41, 144, 129, 118, 51, 126, 33, 85, 24, 0, 61, 92, 70, 15, 17, 50, 83, 30, 28, 91, 60, 48, 133, 55, 63, 7, 131]
```

So I want to use each value in train_idx to find the corresponding dictionary key in available_weights. The expected output should look like this (with a length of all 150 values):

```
new_array = [0.015625, 0.009174311926605505, 0.010869565217391304, ... ,0.01282051282051282, 0.009174311926605505, 0.010869565217391304]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = []
flipped = dict()
for value in train_idx:
    flipped[value] = []
    for key in available_weights:
        if value in available_weights[key]:
            flipped[value].append(key)
            result.append(key)
```